# K&R Book 3-2 Exercise (escape function)

Tags: c, switch-statement

> Write a function escape(s,t) that converts characters like newline and
> tab into visible escape sequences like \n and \t as it copies the
> string t to s. Use a switch. Write a function for the other direction
> as well, converting escape sequences into the real characters.

This is the Exercise 3-2 from K&R book. So I tried to do it. My escape function works properly. But my inverseescape is giving me the same answer as the escape function is giving. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MCC 100

void espace(int* str,int* t);
void inverseescape(int * str,int *t);
void getline(int*);

int main(void){
    int firstarr[MCC];
    int secondarr[MCC];
    int thirdarr[MCC];
    getline(firstarr);
    espace(firstarr,secondarr);
    printf("-----------AFTER ESCAPE------------\n");
    for(int g=0;secondarr[g];g++){
        printf("%c",secondarr[g]);
    }
    inverseescape(secondarr,thirdarr);
    printf("\n-----------AFTER INVERSEESCAPE------------\n");
    for(int g=0;thirdarr[g];g++){
        printf("%c",thirdarr[g]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void getline(int* arr){
    int i=0;
    int c=0;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        arr[i]=c;
        arr[i+1]=0;
        i++;
    }
}

void espace(int* string,int* target){
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(string[i]){
        switch(string[i]){
            case '\a':
                target[j]='\\';
                target[++j]='a';
                target[++j]=0;
                break;
            case '\b':
                target[j]='\\';
                target[++j]='b';
                target[++j]=0;
                break;
            case '\t':
                target[j]='\\';
                target[++j]='t';
                target[++j]=0;
                break;
            case '\n':
                target[j]='\\';
                target[++j]='n';
                target[++j]=0;
                break;
            case '\v':
                target[j]='\\';
                target[++j]='v';
                target[++j]=0;
                break;
            case '\f':
                target[j]='\\';
                target[++j]='f';
                target[++j]=0;
                break;
            case '\r':
                target[j]='\\';
                target[++j]='r';
                target[++j]=0;
                break;
            case '\"':
                target[j]='\\';
                target[++j]='\"';
                target[++j]=0;
                break;
            case '\'':
                target[j]='\\';
                target[++j]='\'';
                target[++j]=0;
                break;
            case '\?':
                target[j]='\\';
                target[++j]='\?';
                target[++j]=0;
                break;
            case '\\':
                target[j]='\\';
                target[++j]='\\';
                target[++j]=0;
                break;
            default:
                target[j]=string[i];
                target[++j]=0;
                break;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

void inverseescape(int* string,int* target){
    int i = 0;
    while(string[i]){
        switch(string[i]){
            case '\\':
            switch(string[i+1]){
                case 'a':
                target[i]='\a';
                case 'b':
                target[i]='\b';
                case 't':
                target[i]='\t';
                case 'n':
                target[i]='\n';
                case 'v':
                target[i]='\v';
                case 'f':
                target[i]='\f';
                case 'r':
                target[i]='\r';
                case '\"':
                target[i]='\"';
                case '\'':
                target[i]='\'';
                case '\?':
                target[i]='\?';
                case '\\':
                target[i]='\\';
            }
            default:
            target[i]=string[i];
        }
        target[++i]=0;
    }
}
```

I am using switch statement first time (and probably last) so the code is not well-written (i guess).

Input:

> shadow
>
> of
>
> the
>
> beast

Output:

> -----------AFTER ESCAPE------------
>
> shadow\nof\nthe\nbeast
>
> -----------AFTER INVERSEESCAPE------------
>
> shadow\nof\nthe\nbeast

Comment: You're missing `break`s in the `inverseescape` case statement.

Comment: the function: `getline()` is a well known system function, exposed in the stdio.h header file.  it has the syntax: `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`   Strongly suggest using a unique name for your function.

Comment: @Muzer Im so dumb... First time using switch.... Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3629249 I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Muzer Could you post it as answer so i can mark your answer as "answer" ?

Comment: suggest replacing the call to `getline()` with a call to `fgets()` then removing the function: `getline()` from your code

Comment: @MuhamedCicak done.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to familiarize with a debugger. Once you step through your unescaping function (a string as simple as `"\n"` will be enough), you'll clearly see all the mistakes you made.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. Actually, i am using debugger a lot (now). But i wasn't when i asked this question. And it is a lot easier to find this kinds of bugs (than asking on stackoverflow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `break` in the `inverseescape` case statement. `case`'s behaviour has the curious property of *falling through* to the statement below unless you explicitly `break` out of the `case`. In this case it's falling through to your `default` case and setting the output to the input.